# double function won't return correct value

Tags: c, double

I don't know why my monthlyPayment function will not return anything. I tried debugging it with the printf function and it seems to be calculating the right value it's just not returning it. When you run it shows that the right value is in the function but it's not getting returned. Any suggestions?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

// calculate monthly payment amount
double monthlyPayment(int loanAmount, int numOfPayments, double interestPerYear) {
        double paymentsPerMonth;
        double interestPerMonth = (interestPerYear / 12) * .01;
        printf("%lf\n", interestPerMonth);
        double numerator = interestPerMonth * pow((1 + interestPerMonth), numOfPayments);
        printf("%lf\n", numerator);
        double denominator = pow((1 + interestPerMonth), numOfPayments) - 1;
        printf("%lf\n", denominator);

        paymentsPerMonth = loanAmount * (numerator / denominator);
        printf("%lf\n", paymentsPerMonth);
        return paymentsPerMonth;


}

int main(void) {
        // init variables
        int loanAmount;
        double interestPerYear;
        int numOfPayments;
        double monthly;
// get loanAmount
        printf("Enter amount of loan: $ ");
        scanf("%d", &loanAmount);
        printf("%d", loanAmount);

        // get interestPerYear
        printf("Enter Interest rate per year: % ");
        scanf("%lf", &interestPerYear);
        printf("%lf", interestPerYear);

        // get numOfPayments
        printf("Enter number of payments: ");
        scanf("%d", &numOfPayments);

        monthly = monthlyPayment(loanAmount, numOfPayments, interestPerYear);
        printf("Monthly: %lf\n", &monthly);

/*
 * interest() = Balance(n-1) * r; (paid interest)
 * principal() = M.Payment - interest(n) (paid principal)
 * Balance(n) = Balance(n-1) - principal(n) (new balance)
 *
 *
 * */
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: `printf("Monthly: %lf\n", &monthly);` remove `&`

Comment: `&` is not needed in this statement - `printf("Monthly: %lf\n", &monthly);`. It should be - `printf("Monthly: %lf\n", monthly);`

Answer (score 0):

you do not need to use **&** before the variable that you want to print. you should write :

`printf("Monthly: %lf\n", monthly);`

instead of

`printf("Monthly: %lf\n", &monthly);`

**&** is practical for scanning not printing.
you can also debug your codes easily with your ide debugger and you don't need to print every single variable.